# Running a script automatically when logging in via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I would like to know if there is a (simple) solution to the following issue:

When I log in with ssh to a specific host, I would like to automatically execute a (bash)script on that host. This way I could -for example- load my aliases on that host.

Definitively the bashrc script is *not* executed; The ssh configuration files do not seem to help in this issue either.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

BTW: The host is running on Gentoo

Comment: Interesting that .bashrc isn't executed. Is there a .profile script that runs? Have you tried that?

Comment: @pjmorse: Post your suggestion as an answer so Stobbej can accept it.

Comment: Ouch. Sorry, I really should have read the comments first. So while my answer is technically the first, it's actually a rip-off of pjmorse's. My apologies again, that was not intended.

Comment: @Olfan: Duplication doesn't mean you don't have something useful to add - in this case, the symlink suggestion.

Comment: Again, thanks to both of you guys(?), for both the solution and the background information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `.bashrc` isn't being run, try `.profile`, which has a similar function. [Different shells use different startup scripts](http://kb.iu.edu/data/abdy.html) at different times, so knowing when to run things is useful.

Answer (score 1):

On many systems where you have a choice of which shell to use, you are put through `~/.profile` only. This way there is no need to find out (and no probably wrong guessing) which shell you're running in and which profile to actually load (.bashrc, .cshrc, .kshrc etc.) and which ones to avoid loading.

The easiest solution in your case would be to create a link (a symbolic one if you prefer visibility) to your favourite shell's startup script as in `ln -s ~/.bashrc ~/.profile`. If you don't intend to ever using anything other than bash, you're set.